# get a instance variable from another class?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I know this is a basic questions but it some how does not work.

I have an `enemy` class which has in its `.h` an instance variable :

```
@interface Enemy : CCLayer
{
    CCSprite *enemy1;
    CGSize winSize ;

}
```

I have another class which is the game class , and which wants to get access to the `enemy1`.
So, this game class is importing the `enemy.h` ,and can use its functions , **BUT** i cant get its pointer `enemy1`, i have tried with no luck :

```
   Enemy *enemy=[[Enemy alloc]init];
    [enemy enemy1]//error
    enemy.enemy1 //error
```

Comment: Did you put the semi-colon at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define a getter for your `enemy1` member. Most recommended way is to declare it as a property :

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly)  CCSprite *enemy1;
```

And then synthesize it in the implementation file :

```
@implementation Enemy 

@synthesize enemy1;
```

The `@property` syntax declares how your member will be treated (at this case only with read permissions and no writing from the outside of the class)

The `@synthesize` syntax generates the getter and setter methods for you depending on how the property has been declared (and since the property is readonly only the getter will be generated)

You could create a getter method yourself but synthesizing make this job for you (including correctly retaining and releasing when necessary)

You can find more information [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html)

Comment: thanks a lot. i will add the property. i was just wondering why i need property- because i know that if a class import another class it gets access to all her instance variables. is it false ?

Comment: I added more detail to why properties are used and also a link to Apple's docs related to this subject

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you should add readonly properties to access those instance variables.

```
@property (nonatomic,assign,readonly) CCSprite *enemy1;
@property (nonatomic,assign,readonly) CGSize winSize;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since ivars by default are protected (means visible only to child classes), you should first declare them as public:

```
@interface Enemy : CCLayer
{
@public
    CCSprite *enemy1;
    CGSize winSize ;

}
```

After that you will be able to access ivars via standart C syntax like this: `enemy->enemy1`.

But why not use properties?

Answer (score 2):

You ought to use @property instead of creating ivars.

```
.h
@property (nonatomic) CCSprite *enemy1;


.m
@synthesize enemy1;
```